# R: Area Graph in ggplot

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have this code:

```
 ggplot(ann_sard,aes(x = Var1, y = value, fill=Var2, group=Var2)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill=Var2),position = "identity",alpha=0.5)+
   geom_line(aes(ymax=value), position="identity")+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkgray"))+
     labs(x="Tempo(anni)",y="Biomassa (t.)",title="Landings annuali")+
      theme_bw()+ theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major =   element_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

the result is: 
[image]

Now, how i can to start the plot directly from x and y axes, without "space" between the area graph and axes? like this for example:
[image]

Comment: `+ coord_cartesian(expand = c(0, 0))`

Comment: @Axeman, it should be `+ coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)` instead. Do you know if there is anyway of specifying the amount of space?

Comment: @toto_tico, yeah use `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous` (or another appropriate `scale_` function) instead where you do get to supply those two values ;). The first is multiplicative (relative) and the second is additive (absolute).

Comment: @Axeman, almost, it modifies both at the same time. But I just found that I can adjust the upper border with `limits`. Basically, `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, TOP))`. TOP specifies how much would you want to extend the graph.